# How to display material-ui cards one next each others with space between them + go to next line when space is over in the row

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

Currently I am displaying on the same line like 10 cards and is enabled by default the scrolling horizontally and the cards are no spaced between them.
I read to use "flex-wrap=wrap" to avoid the scrolling but the cards are put all vertically on a single column...

My code is this

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
 // flexGrow: 1,
  flexWrap: "wrap",
  padding: theme.spacing(2),
  display: "flex",
  width: "50%",
},
 }));
const classes = useStyles();
.
.
.
          <Grid 
                  container
                  direction="row"
                  justify-content="space-evenly "
                 
                >
                  <Grid>
                    <Card>
                      <CardContent>...
```

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set the width of the card?

Comment: no I did not se any width

Comment: Need to set the width of the card, so the card can be show horizontally with flex wrap

Comment: does not work and the card are also overlapping one to each other I tried also giving margin